# re-project from EPSG:4326 to polar projection

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have global georeferenced DEM tiff file in EPSG:4326 and want to re-project in [EPSG:3411](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3411/). I used this command:

`gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3411 global.tif polar.tif`

which resulted in:

[image: screenshot]

What am I missing here, and how can I reproject to polar projection and actually get content reprojected instead this black hole?

`gdalinfo` output:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: global.tif
Size is 2160, 1080
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.166666666666667,-0.166666666666667)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=COARDS/CF-1.0
  NC_GLOBAL#GMT_version=4.4.0
  NC_GLOBAL#history=grdsample -V ETOPO1_Ice_g_gmt4.grd -GETOPO1_Ice_c_gmt4.grd=ni -T
  NC_GLOBAL#node_offset=1
  NC_GLOBAL#title=ETOPO1_Ice_c_gmt4.grd
  x#actual_range=-180, 180
  x#long_name=Longitude
  x#units=degrees
  y#actual_range=-90, 90
  y#long_name=Latitude
  y#units=degrees
  z#_FillValue=-2147483648
  z#actual_range=-10803, 8333
  z#long_name=z
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=2160x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-2147483648
  Metadata:
    NETCDF_VARNAME=z
```

I resized original with gdal_translate and did georeference

Comment: what is the extent of the global.tif file? If it does not reach 90° North, you get a black hole there.

Comment: It reaches 90deg north. It's etopo tiff provided here: http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/. I'll update question with gdalinfo report. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong with your operation.

I clipped the original by -180/180° and +5/90° to get the northern hemisphere only.

Then I used the following command in QGIS:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3411 -dstnodata 0 -of GTiff D:/Download/NEU/ETOPO1_Ice_c_geotiff/Nord.tif D:/Download/NEU/ETOPO1_Ice_c_geotiff/polar1.tif
```

to get the following picture:

[image]

Apart from the white line at +/-180°, it looks good. Maybe you broke something with gdal_translate.

Comment: Perhaps input has to be cropped first, like you did. Following your steps (i.e. cropping the input to north hemisphere) I also get expected result. Trying again on whole globe it fails for some reason. Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: Using the whole globe did not even look good for the Natural Earth vector data overlay. That's why I cropped both to the northern hemisphere in the first round. Maybe this is related to the mathematics of the projection used.